# How do you trace unexpected GCP API calls?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In the GCP API Manager I'm seeing multiple requests come in for the Google Compute Engine API. When I try to filter these requests by credential, it seems that the requests aren't tied to any specific one.

[image]

I tried disabling the API but all that caused was for the requests to 403 as can be seen in the later API calls. Is there a way to trace the source of these requests?

Are they coming from some integration? From GCP itself?

Here's an expanded view when trying to slice the graph by credential for the same time period:

[image]